# Algorithm Configuration Framework for Java / C++

Tags: java, c++, optimization

Is there an open source algorithm configuration (parameter tuning) framework such as [SPOT](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPOT/index.html), [ParamILS](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Projects/ParamILS/) or [I-Race](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/irace/), directly implemented in Java or C++?
I could not find one. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I know that Matlab and R are more suitable for statistical analysis of that type, and that I could for instance [call executables from SPOT](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CF8QFjAI&url=http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4645&ei=gBdzUIyJI6-Q4gTnrIHwBw&usg=AFQjCNGoV_MX4pGR8p0ZRO7PUSKc-Ic2Tg&sig2=rxLO8Ut2GzoAo--lQHJrkA), but I would like to offer a lightweight and easy to setup alternative from within [the tool](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT) I am developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the newest version of SMAC is implemented in Java: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Projects/SMAC/

SMAC is made by the developers of ParamILS and generalizes sequential model-based optimization methods (such as SPOT) to general algorithm configuration (allowing discrete-valued parameters, multiple instances, etc).